# Is there any way to recover from multiple downvotes on an off-topic question?

Tags: support

I'm new to Programmers and asked a question that was considered off topic according to the Programmer's FAQ -- unfortunate cause I was directed to Programmers from StackOverflow (see my comment in the question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130527/how-can-i-find-programming-work-in-south-america))

Anyway, my question was downvoted multiple times. Is there any way to recover my reputation considering the circumstances?

Comment: Hmm, I was wondering why you asked that question, so sorry you were wrongly directed to Programmers by fellow SOpedians.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox it was kind of funny actually. The faq is so blatantly obvious that my question was off topic =p

Comment: This is why we shouldn't let people on SO vote to migrate. They normally just get it wrong.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram In this case OP was directed here from the SO career-development tag wiki. I [nagged about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119369/could-we-add-a-link-to-the-sites-faq-when-the-site-is-proposed-as-an-alternativ) and it no longer points to Programmers as an alternative. Small win, but a win nonetheless.

Comment: A win, indeed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delete the question and then perform a recalculation: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/reputation (click on the button at the bottom of the page) you'll get your reputation back.

You can only do this once in any 24 hour period.

You can only delete a question 48 hours after it was closed. You should have got a message stating this. After 48 hours you'll be able to delete and do a reputation recalculation.

Comment: I voted to delete and clicked the button. I guess I should see the points back soon -- right?

Comment: @Rich Are you sure? I've just checked the question and it's still there.

Comment: Hmm... I see it there too. The only option I had was to vote to delete -- maybe I don't have enough rep to delete?

Comment: I deleted the question and then forced a reputation recal. It's often better to ignore a few downvotes and just work at providing good answers to other questions.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks. I just noted this on the [Delete FAQ Question Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222). I'll give it a try then. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshK **It's often better to ignore a few downvotes and just work at providing good answers to other questions** if you copy this into separate answer I will be first to upvote